# chrome extension chrome.storage how to do a lot of get and set the same time and avoid race condition?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I get an object from `chrome.storage.local.get` and then I want to update that object by using `chrome.storage.local.set` in the callback.

If the callback is executed multiple times a race condition happens. What can I do to avoid this?

I know it can be resolved by `jQuery.defer`, but is there any method to do an atomic update? Or any suggestions to improve my code?

Below is a very simple example:

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){//a lot of at the same time
    //just test
    chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) {
            if(!items.test){
                items.test=[];
            }
            items.test.push(something);
            chrome.storage.local.set(items,function(){});
            console.log('a'+JSON.stringify(items));
        });    
});
```

Comment: You use localStorage for all the frequent get and set from your listener. Setting and getting localStorage is blocking so need need to worry about race conditions. You can then decide some time/event to sync `localStorage` with `chrome.storage`. This works assuming user is working at one computer at one time

Comment: Can't you just move your final `console.log` into the no-op `function(){}`?

Comment: @Teepeemm No, it won't work. Suppose 2 `onCreated` trigger rapidly. Then first 2 `get` happen, and then 2 `set`. State becomes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use `localStorage` in combination with `chrome.storage`.

You can use `localStorage` for all the frequent `get` and `set` from your listener. Setting and getting localStorage is synchronous/blocking so there is no need to worry about race conditions.

You can then decide some idle time/event to sync `localStorage` with `chrome.storage`.

This would work assuming that the user will be using this extension at one computer at any one time.

Comment: Is there easy way to sync `localStorage`  with `chrome.storage`? Or I need to do that by myself? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mirtac you'll need to sync them up yourself. You can iterate through localStorage to get all the key value pairs and then set chrome.storage. Glad it helped.