# How to update an array in storage.local concurrently in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Just want to ask on how to update some data in extension's storage.

This is how I set the data in `chrome.storage`:

```
var storage = chrome.storage.local;
var obj = {},
clientInfo = [];

clientInfo.push({
    "name" : "alde",
    "age" : "21"
});

obj['clientInfo'] = clientInfo;
storage.set(obj,function(){});
```

I want to add another obj in `ClientInfo` array like this:

```
clientInfo.push({
   "name" : "another name",
   "age" : 33
});
```

EDITED

Currently, I still need to get the array to manipulate and save it back to update my storage, I just thought that maybe there's a simplest way to do it.

My problem is just that I have many js files running at the same time and can't append the object synchronously.

Comment: This is already answered in [how to remove data from a object using chrome storage?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28952599/934239), the problem is essentially the same.

Comment: Specifically, you have to get the array, update it, and save it back. You can't manipulate on a finer level with Storage API.

Comment: @Xan - yes, I still need to get the array to manipulate and save it back, I just thought that there's a simplest way to do it. My problem is just that I have many js file running at the same time and can't append the object asynchronously.

Comment: Then there's this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28917824/934239 but no good answer. You should update your question with information from your comment, it makes for a better question.

Comment: Please take a look at any localStorage documentation.

Comment: @ZigMandel Please take a look at the question itself and see that OP means `chrome.storage.local` (unfortunate question title)

Comment: Either way the question is answered on the official documentation.

Comment: @ZigMandel Strongly disagree. Neither point (race condition on read-writes, dealing with objects inside objects) is covered well by the docs.

Comment: There are no objects inside objects and in any case it doesnt make a differencr. Op just needs to learn async programming basics. Its not particular to storage.

Comment: Okay, fine, basics. Can you provide an adequate answer then? Conditions: your storage contains an array that you need to add data to. Several pages within the extension rapidly do that, leading to read-write race condition. Go. Basics!

Comment: @ZigMandel I cleaned up the question to make it reflect the problem. Seriously, let's wager. I pledge to give this question a 250 rep bounty (can't yet), can you make a good answer that deals with the synchronization problem?

Comment: its not a matter of points, your question is still unclear. for starters, javascript is single-threaded so you cant have "many js running at the same time". also, since you are keeping the property as a global "obj", the object is always up to date. Other than the fact that you are not handling storage api errors, the code should work ok. show a case where it doesnt.

Comment: until then all I can offer is that you look at this extension of mine. Uses local/sync storage extensively (sometimes using globals like your case) and does not have concurrency issues. https://github.com/zmandel/Plus-for-Trello/tree/master/source.
If you need to execute code after the storage api finishes, put your code where you currently have an empty "function(){}"

Answer (score -1):

Just rebuild your object properly and call storage.set() again with that new value.

Comment: Actually, I am using that one now but the problem is that I have many js file running at the same time and can't append the object asynchronously.

Comment: @aldesabido You mean "can't ... synchronously", probably.